# HAVING more than 2 books

Tags: sql, having, having-clause

I have to print out only the publishers that published more than 2 books, but for my results, I always get

```
PUB_NAME            |TOTAL      
--------------------------------
Abatis Publishers   |4          
Core Dump Books     |1     <------don't want to print     
Schadenfreude Press |3          
Tenterhooks Press   |5
```

> ERROR 42X01: Syntax error: Encountered "HAVING"

This is my code so far.

```
SELECT pub_name, COUNT(title_name) AS total
FROM publishers 
INNER JOIN titles
ON titles.pub_id = publishers.pub_id
GROUP BY pub_name;
HAVING total > 2;
```

Comment: what has this to do with java?

Comment: Note that your semicolon implies that the query is done after `GROUP BY`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

total is not recognize in HAVING. Try HAVING COUNT(title_name) > 2;

Also remove the ';' in GROUP BY pub_name;

Answer (score 0):

Just use WHERE

```
SELECT p.pub_name, COUNT(t.title_name) AS total
FROM publishers p
INNER JOIN titles t ON t.pub_id = p.pub_id
WHERE COUNT(t.title_name) > 2
GROUP BY p.pub_name;
```